# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value for UUID Field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I have just started learning `laravel`. I'm familiar with `CakePHP`.

I used to use `UUID` field as primary key in my database and in CakePHP, it was quite simple to just change data type of column field to `CHAR(36)` and it works well.

In Laravel, I have modified `users` migration to change `increments` to `uuid` field and set to `primary key`

**CreateUserTable**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->uuid('role_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

But, when I save a new record, it gives error as

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value 
(SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (Anuj, anuj@example.com, password_hash, date-time, date-time))"
```

Comment: laraval has it's syntax u need to respect that as u respect the cakephp syntax

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih This code is perfectly acceptable for Laravel, but there is some validity to that comment. What's the `User` model look like? What does the code for saving this User look like? We would need those in order to debug this further.

Comment: @TimLewis I'm using default registration page to create an account for user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate the UUID as well - unlike auto incrementing unsigned integer keys, the UUID field doesn't just populate itself.

One popular and very simple-to-use such package is alsofronie/eloquent-uuid, which is available here: https://github.com/alsofronie/eloquent-uuid

Comment: So, I need to create this manually and `Laravel` does not create it on it's own like `CakePHP`?

Comment: I installed this plugin. But again it says same error. Do I need to make any further modification to `Model` or migration file?

Comment: No, It has nothing more than installing and changing field type to `uuid`, which I have already done in the migration.

Comment: The instructions say "In order to use this in your models, just put use Uuid[32|Binary]ModelTrait;:" and a code example.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But, in example `User` model extends `Eloquent` while default user model in my app extends `Authenticable`. Further more, adding `Uuid[32|Binary]ModelTrait;` is giving syntaxt error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' or '{'`.

Answer (score 3):

What I did for this one is to create a Trait for Models that uses UUID:

```
trait WithUuid
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string) Uuid::generate(4);
        });
    }

    public function initializeHasUuid()
    {
        $this->incrementing = false;
        $this->keyType = 'string';
    }
}
```

then on your Model just declare that Trait:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use WithUuid;

   // rest of your Code
}
```

So you don't have to create a new one everytime you create something.